# Why is BCrypt returning false for all comparisons on a user's login after the script is restarted?

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose, bcrypt

I am currently using Mongoose, Node.js, and BCrypt for authentication to login to my website. However, every time the server crashes, or is restarted abruptly, the login system seems to fail. Currently, the login function pulls the user's hashed password from the database and checks it against a hashed version of the submitted password with the bcrypt.compare() function. It works fine during normal operation but after the server crashes or is restarted abruptyly, is returns false no matter if the password is correct or not.

The strange part is that as long as the person resets their password and a new password is issued, the problem is fixed and everything works fine again for just that user's account.

Any ideas on what's happening here? I can share more code if needed.

Comment: I have some problem too. Please, I need help.